# Get email when an event is added to Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I am encountering several of web pages that address email reminders for SharePoint calendars. But, I would like to know how to send an email to someone when any event is added to the calendar. How can I do this or is there a tutorial that shows how to do this? From what I've read so far I need to create a workflow but the workflow options are not clear on what needs to be configured. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Send an email" action to alert the user when a new item is created in Calendar list:
[image]

Select the workflow **Start Options** as shown below:

[image]